# Android Image view shows up after setVisibility gone

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new to android and try to build an android application.

I stack two image view together. What I want to do is when user click the top image, the bottom one shows up. When user click the bottom image, the top one shows up.

The problem is after I click the top image, the bottom image shows up for a second then the top image shows up again.

Here is the code:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
ImageView top = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.top);
top.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
               View parent = (View)v.getParent();
               ImageView top =            
                            (ImageView)parent.findViewById(R.id.top);
               top.setVisibility( View.GONE );

               ImageView bottom =    
                            (ImageView)parent.findViewById(R.id.bottom);
               bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

   ImageView bottom = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom);
   bottom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
              View parent = (View)v.getParent();
              ImageView top = 
                        (ImageView)parent.findViewById(R.id.top);
              top.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

              ImageView bottom =          
                        (ImageView)parent.findViewById(R.id.bottom);
              bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   });
```

Here is the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/stop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ok" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: first of all what is this view !!!
ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand);

Comment: I have modified the code I posted. ImageView iv is the image on the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView top = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.top);
        top.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View parent = (View) v.getParent();
                ImageView top = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.top);
                top.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                ImageView bottom = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.bottom);
                bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        ImageView bottom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom);
        bottom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View parent = (View) v.getParent();
                ImageView top = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.top);
                top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ImageView bottom = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.bottom);
                bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }  

}
```

i tried the above code and its working and it does not change the image.

Comment: Could the above code change the image each time user clicked?

Comment: yes it changed the image each time the user clicked